# 12.04 wifi signal very weak

Tags: wireless, signal

Ii am new people in Ubuntu
I am using 12.04 version , but my wifi signal very weak
 My router beside me only , my signal also only 50% ...
Anybody know how to fix it?i have try to research solution, but fail.
Any one can tell me how to increase my wifi signal?
Thank you.

Comment: hi
it display
E: Unable to locate package linux-firmware-nonfree
thank

Comment: if so, install it: `sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree`

Comment: can already install done,after that i need to do what?

Comment: purge and reinstall it. `sudo apt-get --purge autoremove linux-firmware-nonfree && sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree`

Comment: yes all done,but my wifi signal still 2 line only,T_T
hi ,do u have skype?may i added you and chat?

Answer (score 0):

First of all check your wifi card TX power by turn on your wifi and type in terminal

```
sudo iwconfig
```

and check your Tx power it should be **15-20** (Average card power.), if it is less than 15 than your card is weak and not able to recieve strong signal.

If you have powerful card with min 15 TX power than probably everything is fine. because your getting **50% signals** it means everthing fine with **packages** and wifi.

**Tip : you can use aluminum paper around your wifi antennae to boost your signal.**

Comment: hi
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"XDD"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.417 GHz  Access Point: 00:14:D1:9E:3D:04   
          Bit Rate=14.4 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=38/70  Signal level=-72 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:100  Invalid misc:145   Missed beacon:0

this is i beside my router,if i move far a bit then cannot connect,keep ask for wifi password

Comment: hi,I am using driver rt2800pci

Comment: Driver is fine and you card have 20TX power which is more enough, its mean your hardeware doing well, i think your router haven't transmission power, try to connect handheld device with it, see if it is getting strong signals ?

Comment: hi,my other laptop in window 7 's signals is full,do not why only in ubuntu 12.04 LTS version will facing this problem.
thank for your reply,^_^

Answer (score 0):

Go to **system settings >> software sources >> Additional driver**

on your wifi card tick on using broadcomXXXX wifi card. (your wifi card name)

and then apply changes.

if it is already ticked then **click on do not use the device and apply changes** then follow above steps.

Comment: hi ,do u have skype?may i added you and chat?

Comment: hi izit this got any problem?

02:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 18ec
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
 Memory at c2510000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
 Capabilities: <access denied>
 Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
 Kernel modules: rt2800pci

Comment: Jason mine ISP is in the maintainance ..... I m not getting much speed for skype :(

Comment: T_T my wifi signal still very weak= =